# Why does my ohm meter briefly display a very large resistance before slowly increasing to OL?

Tags: resistance, wiring, ohmmeter

I have 3 single conductor wires running from my house out to my barn.  They have never been used for anything.  When I measure the resistance across the ends of the 3 wires I would expect them to all show OL since they are not connected.  In two cases, that is what I get.  When I measure across the black and white wires, though, I read somewhere in the vicinity of 38 megaohms and the reading slowly increases up to just shy of 41 Megaohms and then displays OL.  I'm using an inexpensive Southwire multimeter with auto ranging.

This only and always happens between the black and white wires.  It never happens between red and white or red and black.  Any insight to what is going on here would be appreciated.

Comment: You are seeing the capacitance measured. The cap is formed by the two conductors and dielectric (jacket) in between, check Wikipedia for "capacitor". The ohm meter flows known current to a resistor to measure the voltage across the R, then calculates R = V/I. When the ohm meter measures a cap, the cap is charged (V = 1/C * I * dt, integration of the charge). Thus the time goes, the charged voltage increases.... Warm Welcome to the site..

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that.  And so quickly.  I thought something like that might be going on but just thought it odd that I wasn't seeing it with the other wires.  Thanks again.

Comment: Are you expecting to see any particular values when measuring?  It's possible there's a very high impedance path in between those two cables (>40MOhm) formed by something, even just some parasitics that can act as a capacitor and slowly ramp up what your DMM will show for resistance, after measuring the resistance between those two wires have you tried reversing which probe from you DMM is on which wire to see if there are any differences?

Comment: I was checking the wires to verify there were no direct shorts and that the wires in the house were the ones running out to the barn since I did not run them.  The previous owner ran a lot of wires around the property "just in case" when he built the house.  in the process of verifying what goes where I stumbled on this odd reading.  And yes I did try reversing leads and got the same results.  I think Jay nailed it above.  Thanks...

Comment: Since they use DC , it indicates some possible moisture leakage in that pair which has 80 times more capacitance per unit length affected if wet, but not a problem yet.

Comment: Try measuring from those wires to a known-good Earth connection - If you see the same 38-41MΩ, the wiring is probably wet. In any case, ensure it is fused properly just in case.

Comment: What do you want to use these wires for?

Comment: As far as usage... there is an interlock switch on my house panel and I planned on using these wires to feed it so that I can run my generator out at the barn.

Answer (score 2):

Two parallel metal conductors make a capacitor and the ohm meter gets confused by this capacitance (if the meter has a capacitance mode you could use that to measure the capacitance between the wires). The other thing that is happening is there is *some resistance* between the wires that the meter can measure. This could be from insulation or even a breakdown of the insulation or something conducting between wires. Many insulations resistance reads above 100MegΩ

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEjg83.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Moisture would appear to be the culprit.  Had some rain last night and now I am seeing this across all wire combinations.  Although slightly different readings.

Comment: Now black to white still starts around 38 megaohms but red to black starts around 25 megaohms and red to white starts around 19 megaohms before they all climb to about 40.50 megaohms before going to OL.                                                           As far as usage... there is an interlock switch on my house panel and I planned on using these wires to feed it so that I can run my generator out at the barn.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**:
I have a Digital MultiMeter (DMM) that shows the same behavior, aggravated at its highest resistance range. I will divide the answer in 2 parts:

- one related to the DMM way of measuring resistance,
- another to demonstrate you may have found a minor leakage current in the household wiring.

At the end, I share a DIY continuity/isolation tester, more useful in unpowered household wirings.

### **Answer Part 1 - DMM related cause**:

The DMM has its ohmmeter feature applying a certain current (or voltage+resistance) for a selected resistance range.  This current has to stabilize before DMM's internal millivolt reading in the ohmmeter circuit to be able to have a constant reading within the range.
One way of smoothing out towards a stable reading is to use an **internal RC circuit**. That “C” is at least an internal capacitor in the DMM and the external circuit can add to the overall capacitance; this equivalent C will take longer to charge if the measuring current is smaller.
**For low range readings as 200 Ω or 2 KΩ**, this current is larger, the **equivalent RC “charges” faster**, typically in less than half a second; here, the DMM does not have time to show this transient voltage buildup and **OverLoad (OL) reading is seen almost immediately**.

On several DMMs, **the higher the Full-Scale Reading (FSR), the smaller the measuring current, and reading takes a long time to stabilize.** And until that equivalent C is fully charged, DMM will show an increasing resistance, until eventually reaching the OL reading.

**To demonstrate this reduced testing current** (under the short-circuit of an ammeter) **for each increased resistance range**, I used another DMM with higher precision and auto range to measure the currents of my common-day DMM, which has its range manually selected, taking photos for each measuring set - see the attached picture collage.

***These slower readings happen even with the terminal leads not touching anything***: the OL or “out of range” message takes longer to appear as the FSR range increases.
As I said, it will become worse / slower if the Device Under Test (DUT) has capacitors in the measured circuit, including the distributed capacitance of long wires.

---

### **Answer Part 2 - Household wiring with potential minor leakage**:

> When I measure the resistance across the ends of the 3 wires I would expect them to all show OL since they are not connected.
>
> - In two cases, that is what I get.
> - When I measure across the black and white wires, though, I read somewhere in the vicinity of 38 megaohms and the reading slowly increases up to just shy of 41 Megaohms and then displays OL.

From what you said, you may also have a wetted or humid wiring junction, that has a minuscule current leakage at DMM's low testing voltages.
Being a DC current, **a minuscule DC current could create a galvanic polarization on any not-fully insulated area**.  This would increase the apparent resistance (more like an impedance, with small capacitance near wetted terminals or *electrodes*).
These polarization phenomena happen under low voltage differentials, as from DMM. Under higher voltages, as V.test > 1~2 Volts, not only does this polarization and "corrosion" of electrodes exist but also happens a slow dissociation of water (electrolysis: one electrode ->  oxygen; another -> hydrogen).

To demonstrate that this polarization and variable (non-ohmic) behavior happens with a DMM and wet wiring, I designed and made an experiment that records visually - by using a Digital Storage Oscilloscope (DSO) - the variable resistance as a variable voltage on the DMM along the testing time.

- **Photo #1**: DSO input impedance with alligator clips is 400K Ohm.
- **Photo #2**: Open circuit voltage read in the DSO for the DMM's Ohmmeter at 200K range is 254 mV.
  In this case, the DMM is trying to read DSO's resistance as 400K and returns OL (or "1__._" = out of range). All wiring is still dry.
- **Photo #3**: Wetting two small pieces of flexible copper wire (about 1.5 cm) cleaned and with sandpaper, initial resistance was measured as 26 KOhm. DSO shows this as a pronounced voltage drop, from initial 254 mV to ~40mV.
- **Photo #4**: After +/- 30s, resistance continually increases to 50.8KOhm, where DSO marks this increase to +/- 100mV. (100 mV/div and 5 s/div).
- **Larger Photo #5**: After **1 minute, resistance increases four times**, to R = 102KOhm. The wet test condition was made with sandpapered copper wires and filtered water, with Total Dissolved Solids: TDS ~= 50.

[image]

---

### **Alert Note**:

Using a **DMM** in the Megohm range **to check household wiring is just not adequate**, as the DMM **readings can be misleading**.
For instance, one circuit could have a faulty device or an electronic circuit connected to it (I mean between Line and Neutral) and appear to be fully insulated at the DMM very low voltage supply. But at higher voltages, it starts to conduct. Think in a circuit as a Zener diode, an electronic lamp ballast (with a diode bridge), or even a neon lamp: all of them will just start to conduct above 1V~2V, up to 80V (as the neon).

> 3 single *conductor wires* running from my *house* out to my barn. They have never been used for anything. When I measure the resistance across the ends of the 3 wires I would expect them to all show OL since they are not connected.

For instance: When a similar DMM to mine is used in the 200 Ohm reading, the testing voltage is bigger than 2 Volts - and only in that range.
But if I had a leakage as big as say, 300 Ohms (= 48W under 120Vac) it simply could not be detected!
Most CFL or LED lamps consume much less than 48W, so they could be electrically connected to the wiring, but for the DMM the wiring would appear as "nothing is connected" or "fully insulated" in this 200 Ohm range; for the other ranges, the DMM would not have enough voltage to pass through the rectifier stage.

**Bottomline:** Using a DMM to test the household wiring with modern appliances, we all could have a **false perception of "all good"** when in fact we could **"have a problem"**.

---

### **A DIY testing device**:

Using 2x 9V batteries in series with a LED+1K resistor makes a **useful device for *unpowered* household circuits**.
It will provide about 16V along the circuit, which is about 10% of peak rated line voltage, but if you wish to test at 25V, use 3x 9V, and change R = 2K2.  Here is the basic circuit, using two 9V batteries:

[image]

The circuit shows the main LED D1 and an optional LED D2, in anti-parallel to avoid reverse voltage in the main LED (they damage for Voltages < -5V). In the case of the optional LED lighting-up, you know something (batteries or LED) was assembled backward.
The short circuit current at the device's terminals will be limited to about 16 mA and LED D1 will shine in high brightness. While *indoors*, one could see the LED D1 glowing with as little as 0,5 mA (use a 33K to “calibrate” your eyes).  Observe in this case, that **you now have a visual indication in the 20KΩ range of a DMM**, but using a **more representative voltage (16V)**.

Guideline of use:

- Check if the LED D1 does NOT glow at all - check in both polarities (reversing the "+" and "-"). This is a good starting point.
- If LED glows dimly, then investigate better, as you may have wetted or a  poor insulation, as commonly caused by water ingress. IF LED brightness is not constant, suspicion increases.
- For greater sensitivity or quantitative accuracy, measure the DC voltage drop in the  1K resistor (as shown). It will tell you the leaking current.

I.leak [mA] =  V.dmm [Volt] / 1 [KOhm] , or simply:

**I.leak [in mA] = V.dmm [reading in V]**

---

**Upgraded Circuit (still draft)**
Features and improvements:

- LED brightness is 11 mA constant up to 70K Ohm.
- Buzzer (12V) was added for faster use - no need to look to check if LED is On/Off anymore.
  Full volume up to 70K Ohm too.
- Sensitivity detection goes to 200K Ohm. Brightness and sound are reduced gradually to zero.
- Sensitivity can be adjusted proportionally to R4:
  Detection grows for R4 > 10K; sensitivity lowers for R4 < 10K.
  Suggested  range: 1K < R4 < 47K.
- Original higher current (15mA) testing lead is maintained for a buzzer-free operation and a less sensitive test.
- Both Positive leads operate up to ~ 15V above the Negative lead.
  No more testing wiring resistance and insulations with just 50mV to 200mV.

I provided the **circuit made with CircuitLab**, so anyone can customize and simulate with creativity: Changing R4, or the Wiring Resistances (R_wiring_DUT), and Capacitances (C_wiring_DUT) - change at will.
Further below is the **DC-sweep simulation** showing the current and voltage results at the collector of the transistor for variable Wiring Resistances (R_wiring_DUT) between 10K and 1M.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5e1X0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

**Final note/Disclaimer**: *The DIY continuity tester does not replace a high voltage tester or other professional-rated equipment*, but it is simpler, faster, and would give more confidence the household wires are “not bad” - at least when compared with a straight DMM reading.

I hope it's useful for you! And I would appreciate your feedback.